# Error while creating/editing route in AWS cloudformation - Route Table has a conflicting issue with the gateway igw-xxx

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have configured one public and one private subnet within a vpc and have the respective route tables for both private and public subnets. I have also created an internet gateway and have attached/associated with the public subnet and a nat gateway and associated it with the private gateway.

I have two EC2 instances, one running on private subnet (us-east-1b) and the other on the public subnet (us-east-1a). I couldn't ssh to the EC2 instance in the public subnet and learnt that I have to have an entry in the route table of the public subnet as (destination- 0.0.0.0/0 and target pointed to igw-xxx which is the internet gateway). When I clicked on edit routes>create new routes and entered these values and clicked create route , I receive an error :

> 'Route table has conflicting association with the gateway igw-xxx'.

I have only one entry in the public subnet's route table which is destination - 10.200.0.0/16 and target - local
What could be the reason ?

Reference screenshots -

Image of the route table and associated public subnet -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DerkC.jpg

Image showing attached Internet gateway to the route table associated with public subnet -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IaF4.jpg

When i try to edit/add this route to the route table associated with the public subnet since I need internet connectivity-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCyKo.jpg

I get this error -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W8CM.jpg

Comment: Can you please provide some screenshots?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will be providing some in a few minutes @Paolo

Comment: Screenshots have been posted! @Paolo

Comment: Why did you create the edge association?

Comment: @Paolo , that is needed for internet access for EC2 instance in the public subnet. The Internet gateway has to be 'attached' as edge association to the route table.

Comment: You think it's needed but like you said, you aren't able to connect to the instance in the public subnet. Try removing the edge association and adding an actual route to the internet gateway in the route table

Comment: The actual route to the internet in the internet gateway for IPV4 is 0.0.0.0/0 which is addressed here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html





Takes a bit of scrolling before you can find the first two tables.

Comment: I know. My point is that maybe to add the route to the route table as you are trying to do you might need to delete the edge association first

Comment: Tried that too , instead of creating edge association first and adding route later , tried the reverse way and encountered this error while adding edge association: 'Route table contains unsupported route destination. The unsupported route destination is less specific than or non overlapping with VPC local CIDR'